# Does Star Trek ever allude to Sulu's sexual orientation?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-tos, continuity, sexuality

George Takei has recently renewed his celebrity via social media and especially his support for gay rights.  Did Hikaru Sulu (Takei's character in Star Trek) ever have a lover or love interest in the TV show, films or books?  If not, is it possible that Sulu is, like his portrayer, homosexual?

Now, I *know* that an actor's sexuality and the sexuality of a character they play don't need to have anything to do with each other.  For instance, we know that while Captain Kirk was a promiscuous ball of interspecies lust, Shatner in real life was/is practically celibate.  OK, I made that up, but my point is it **could** be true.

**Update** I think I wasn't clear in my question -- what I meant was not whether Sulu was revealed as gay, but rather did Sulu's sexual orientation of any kind (gay *or* straight) ever get revealed?  Did he ever have a love or love interest that was male *or* female?

Comment: OOooooooh my...

Comment: Come on! You *have* to link to [the épée picture](http://images.wikia.com/memoryalpha/en/images/5/53/Sulu_Fencing.jpg)...

Comment: @dmckee I'm worried I've already tread into "reinforcing stereoptypes" land

Comment: bonus question is whether any of the actors have ever discussed if Takei was out of the closet when the original show was being shot, and what everyone thought about it if he was.  I know they were an open minded group for the time, but it was still quite a while ago...

Comment: What level of canon are you looking for?  The TV Series only?  The related books?  Fan-fic?  (The last will almost certainly have examples, but probably shouldn't be counted.)  I don't recall anything in the novels I've read, but might want to clarify, as there might be such info in a few of them.

Comment: @Keith - I'll include books.  But I'd consider TV series and movie true canon and I imagine it'd be ok for Abrams to contradict the book.  But no Fan-fic.

Comment: +1 for "Shatner in real life was/is practically celibate".

Comment: @KeithHWeston - don't knock down fanfics. cracked.com - not without reason - claimed that [Oresteia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oresteia) was one of the original fanfics :)

Comment: @zipquincy If challenged on that you claim that the whole point is that the *Asian* Sulu is a secret devote of a *European* sword system. Then give them your best stupid look and wait to see if *they* will claim it makes him look light in the loafers... Obviously if it had been a katana they'd have had a point.

Comment: @Zipquincy I removed the last paragraph from your question because it didn't have anything to do with what the question is about. It's what you want to happen with the series, but isn't relavant to the question.

Comment: @OghmaOsiris oh come on, if I can't target JJ Abrams on the scifi Q&A board what use is life?!  :)  Whatever

Comment: I have some memory of Patrick Stewart (in an interview focusing on _[Jeffrey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeffrey_(film))_) mentioning Roddenberry was homophobic for much of his life, and only came around during (pre-)production of _TNG_. If my memory is accurate and that's true, I would be surprised if Takei was out, at least to the entire cast, at that time.

Comment: Your latest edit appears to be an attempt to answer your own question. It would be better added as an answer, not an edit to the original question.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Oddly enough, Star Trek and homosexuality is like fire and water. It's always been something they danced around, perpetuating heterosexual relationships as the only existing and valid form. There's even a whole [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexuality_in_Star_Trek#LGBT_in_Star_Trek), discussing this.

Kate Mulgrew once said in [an interview](http://www.totallykate.com/teafive/outiname.html):

> Well, one would think that Hollywood would be more open-minded at this point, since essentially the whole town is run by the gay community. It makes very little sense if you think about it. **No, Star Trek is very strangely by the book in this regard. Rick Berman, who is a very sagacious man, has been very firm about certain things. I've approached him many, many times over the years about getting a gay character on the show--one whom we could really love, not just a guest star.** Y'know, we had blacks, Asians, we even had a handicapped character--and so I thought, this is now beginning to look a bit absurd. And he said, "In due time." And so, I'm suspecting that on Enterprise they will do something to this effect. I couldn't get it done on mine. And I am sorry for that.

<sup>(emphasis added)</sup>

So, as you can see, the actual (i.e. the pre-Abrams era) Star Trek doesn't touch that topic. Yes, there are a few exceptions in TNG, DS9 and even *very* slightly in VOY, but nothing concrete.

Since Abrams has a habit of changing Star Trek (so far for the worse, if you ask me), maybe he'll get lucky and change something for the better. But I wouldn't bet on it.

---

### Edit: You bring up the question whether changing the Sulu in the new timline-skewed films would have an impact on the "old" Sulu we knew in TOS.

*That's* a tricky question, and it is difficult to even discuss without offending people (so, I hope I manage). There're several assumptions you have to take into account: Is sexual preference a genetic trait, pure choice, environmental, upbringing, ...? I've no idea, but I'm given to understand that some people take offence in some of them.

However, these *theories* all influence whether changing his preference in post 2009 productions would imply assertions about TOS-Sulu. For instance, if its genetic, the connection is obvious; Somebody going back in his life-time (we can assume Sulu to be about the age of Kirk, right?) wouldn't effect a change in his DNA. Similarly, if the environment theory applies, the changed conditions of his life (that *were* affected) could support a change of preference.

So, featuring any indication of Sulu's sexuality in new films without careful consideration could lead to drastic continuity errors that would imply statements about LGBT that the producers are (if they are the slightest considerate) not going to be willing to make.

Comment: Or like 'Blood and Fire' --http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blood_and_Fire_(Star_Trek:_The_Next_Generation)

Comment: I love Kate Mulgrew more and more :)

Comment: see my clarification avove.

Comment: @zipquincy: I see. Well, according to Star Trek dogma, everybody's heterosexual by default. No exceptions. Period. -- Other than that I don't recall any such occurrences of Sulu.

Comment: @bitmask - imagining this dogma was usurped, and then they revealed in the next Star Trek new-timeline movie that Sulu was gay.  would that contradict any actual events from other movies, TV and books (other than an underlying assumption that everyone is hetero?)?

Comment: @zipquincy The new Star Trek takes place in an alternate timeline, so nothing can be contradicted.

Comment: @CamelBlues - not exactly.  Nothing occurring _after_ the events in the new "Star Trek" movie can be contradicted.  However, presumably events _before_ that movie, as well as fundamental laws and rules of the ST universe _should_ remain as consistent as possible.  This should include the sexual orientation of the ST characters which would have already been determined by the time of these events...  Just like it would not make sense for the new timeline to make Spock Romulan instead of Vulcan.

Comment: @zipquincy: See my edit, please.

Comment: @zipquincy I disagree. According to the new Star Trek movie co-writer, Kirk's backstory is totally different in the movie from TOS http://trekmovie.com/2008/12/11/bob-orci-explains-how-the-new-star-trek-movie-fits-with-trek-canon-and-real-science/

Comment: @CamelBlues: Yes and no. See my update. It's hard (impossible?) to tell at which point and how Sulu's conception+life was influenced by this random event (Nero travelling back through time).

Comment: @bitmask "would imply statements about LGBT that the producers are (if they are the slightest considerate) not going to be willing to make." here, I think, you get to the root of it.

Comment: @CamelBlues Kirk's backstory is different because the divergence happened at his birth.  Characters born before the divergence (characters older than Kirk) would be genetically identical to the original TOS, while the ones born afterwards may have been affected by the divergence.

Comment: @Izkata In terms of the new Star Trek movie vs. the established canon, much more than Kirk's backstory is different. For example, in the original TOS, the Enterpise was built in San Fransisco. In the new Star Trek, the Enterprise was built in Iowa. It's not a divergence, it's an entirely different universe.

Comment: @CamelBlues: I don't see how that's relevant. The decision where to build the Enterprise can be considered to have been made after Kirk's birth.

Comment: "maybe he'll get lucky" is a deeply unfortunate phrase in a post about sexuality :)

Comment: "even very slightly in VOY" For example? And who was the "handicapped character"? Suder? Or is it a tenuous reference to the Doctor's struggle for liberty and recognition?

Comment: Maybe Tuvok in Riddles, or Seven with her emotional struggles. Hmm.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: In one episode (I can't remember the name) the Doctor's program is stored in Seven's implants and he can take concious control of her body. He then goes on to flirt with a female humanoid alien while possessing Seven's body. It's a bit of a stretch, though. And the handicapped character ... well, there'd be four people that come to mind. Most likely it could allude to the Doctor being trapped in sickbay, secondly it might be Seven, who has several physical handicaps. B'Elanna struggles with some psychological issues, and there's of course Mr. Paris.

Comment: @bitmask: Oh yes, _Body and Soul_. What are Seven's "physical handicaps"? By all accounts she is stronger and more durable than the other humans on board, though she _does_ need medical attention to remain healthy that is true.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Well, medical attention is one thing (I would describe that as clearly handicapped). Additionally, she requires special equipment to "sleep" and being separated from that equipment for too long will cause severe health problems, possibly even death (I'm speculating). Finally (although a minor handicap) she is extremely sensitive to ingesting ethanol, which *can* lead to partial societal ostracism.

Comment: @bitmask: Well I think you're reaching a bit now

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Yes, I am. These were the closest I could think of. At least of the regular cast, and Mulgrew was talking about regular cast members, not single-episode ones, I think. But even in single episodes I can't remember any obviously handicapped one-episode character.

Comment: @bitmask: Oh, presumably Tuvok in _Year of Hell_.

Answer (score 26):

There are several pieces of evidence which could be taken to suggest that Sulu is probably attracted to women, but none of them strike me as definitive (and in any case he could always be bi):

- In "Mirror, Mirror", mirror-Sulu hits on Uhura, but the DS9 mirror-universe episodes suggest that sexuality need not be preserved across universes so this doesn't necessarily imply anything about Sulu himself.
- In the animated episode "The Magicks of Megas-Tu", Sulu conjures up a beautiful woman using magic.
- His daughter Demora appears in *Generations*, but there's no on-screen indication of who her mother is, and expanded-universe mentions of her are contradictory on this point.

Comment: awesome answer from a detail point of view instead of broader point of view like the others.  Can you elaborate on" DS9 mirror-universe episodes suggest that sexuality need not be preserved across universes"?  I never watched DS9 more than a few times, and this also seems to contradict other's claims that ST is a all-sexuality-is-hetero zone.

Comment: Note that the Federation *could* have the technology to allow male-male reproduction (which as far as I can tell (as a layman) isn't *that* far fetched).

Comment: @zipquincy: Mirror-Kira is pretty clearly bi -- she's attracted to her own counterpart in "Crossover" and in some sort of (perhaps not-entirely-consensual) relationship with mirror-Ezri in "The Emperor's New Cloak". The end of "The Emperor's New Cloak" also implies a budding relationship between mirror-Ezri and mirror-Leeta. There's no evidence that the original-universe versions of any of the three women aren't entirely straight. I'd assume this is one of the things bitmask was thinking of with eir "few exceptions" sentence...

Comment: @zipquincy: It's very strongly implied that Mirror-Kira has sex with women as well as men. Although it's not clear if it's because her preferences differ, or she has the same preferences but is more sexually active, or is more interested in the power dynamics (since she effectively enslaves much of the station) than gender.

Comment: @bitmask: Absolutely -- male-male reproduction has to be easier than human-Vulan reproduction, right? Or he could have used IVF, or any number of other possibilities. Which is why I wouldn't consider it remotely definitive, but it seemed worth mentioning.

Comment: @Micah: "Human-Vulcan reproduction." In theory, it is quite possible that Humans and Vulcans are compatible by nature. The underlaying foundation for this is set in the ST universe that all species have one common ancestor. That would allow inter-racial breeds if the DNA isn't altered too much. *Big Warning Sign: I have no idea what "altered too much" is or how much.*

Comment: @Bobby: It's hard to know, since Star Trek canon contradicts both itself and most known science on this point. But the divergence point between humans and Vulcans is considerably further back than the divergence point between humans and, say, bonobos -- and I'm pretty sure male-male reproduction would be a lot easier than human-bonobo reproduction.

Comment: In "The Naked Time", an intoxicated Sulu also seems interested in Uhura; between that and "Mirror, Mirror" I'd conclude that Sulu is generally attracted to her but too professional to make a move on her.

Comment: Remember also that in the episode *The Naked Time*, Sulu says he will defend Uhura from the other 'evil' people (sorry for the paraphrase).  Although this doesn't address his orientation, it is worthy of adding (although he was intoxicated by the disease at the time).

Comment: There is also this exchange between Sulu and another crewmember in "Mudd's Women", when they are discussing the super-sexy women (thanks to the 'Venus drug') Mudd has brought on board: **SULU: You're on duty, Johnny-o. Back to reality. 
FARRELL: You can feel their eyes when they look at you, like something grabbing hold of you. Did you notice that? 
SULU: I noticed. How I noticed. Come on, Johnny.** Both the line and the way Takei played it suggest the intention was that Sulu found the women very attractive too and had to make an effort to keep his mind on his job.

Comment: Also, in "The Way to Eden", Sulu has some non-specific interaction with one of the female "space hippies". Given the interaction and alluded back-story between Chekov and Irina, one might reasonably extrapolate some sort of sexual subtext to Sulu's also.

Answer (score 8):

I don't have any conclusive in-universe proof, but George Takei thinks that Sulu is straight. After [news recently broke](http://www.heraldsun.com.au/entertainment/movies/star-trek-beyond-favourite-mr-sulu-has-come-out-as-castmates-reflect-on-the-death-of-anton-yelchin/news-story/51909410e4e465f825470c4dfbcc17ec?nk=3729557f515ef0b2b7bf6c22d2dfd514-1468228429) that the new movie [*Star Trek Beyond*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2660888/) would reveal Sulu as gay [Takei said](http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/news/george-takei-reacts-gay-sulu-909154) that it was "unfortunate":

> I’m delighted that there’s a gay character. Unfortunately, it’s a twisting of Gene’s creation, to which he put in so much thought. I think it’s really unfortunate.

Takei tried to convince the film makers to not make Sulu gay and instead create a new gay character:

> I told him, "Be imaginative and create a character who has a history of being gay, rather than Sulu, who had been straight all this time, suddenly being revealed as being closeted."

Along with the inconclusive evidence offered in other answers that [Hollywood Reporter article](http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/news/george-takei-reacts-gay-sulu-909154) mentions that the 1995 novel *The Captain's Daughter* says that Sulu's daughter was the result of a one-night stand with a glamazon, a "very athletic, powerful and stunningly gorgeous woman", which would also support him not being gay.

Answer (score 6):

**No**. This answer is based on speculation about how well the cast knew Takei and the fact that Roddenberry first considered including gay characters in the late 80s, in response to a request from a gay fan.

Star Trek TOS ran from 1966-1969. George Takei 'officially' came out in 2005, even though it had been an 'open secret' that he was gay in the 1970s (according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/George_Takei)).

William Shatner, upon getting 'snubbed' from Takei's wedding, made a [statement](http://www.huffingtonpost.com/2008/10/22/william-shatner-slams-geo_n_136781.html) indicating that during the actual production of TOS, he didn't know Takei very well.

> [Takei] would come in for a day or two, as evidenced by the part he
>   played. Then on the movies, there occasionally.

I would assume that if Shatner didn't know him too well, it would be hard to put in allusion to his sexuality in TOS. Keep in mind that Star Trek has *never* had an openly gay character.

Gene Roddenberry [promised](http://www.sciscoop.com/2003-2-5-13436-15446.html) to do an episode of TNG, Blood and Fire, that would feature gay crewmen. The episode was shelved and was never produced. Later, the script was re-written for [Star Trek New Voyages](http://www.startreknewvoyages.com/?page_id=389).

Comment: oops, see my clarification above.

Answer (score 2):

There is an important new update

http://www.vanityfair.com/hollywood/2016/07/sulu-gay-star-trek-john-cho

> Looks like Star Trek Beyond will boldly go where no Star Trek film has
>   gone before: Melbourne’s Herald Sun reports that the upcoming movie
>   will depict U.S.S. Enterprise helmsman Hikaru Sulu as a gay man
>   raising a daughter with his partner. (Vanity Fair has reached out to
>   Paramount for confirmation and comment, and will update this post
>   accordingly when we hear back.)

When this is officially confirmed I will accept this as the answer.

Comment: It's been confirmed; https://www.theguardian.com/film/2016/jul/08/simon-pegg-defends-gay-sulu-after-george-takei-criticism

Comment: Relevant http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/entertainment-arts-36744328

Comment: Note that this doesn't shed any light on the sexual orientation of the original Sulu. Since Sulu is younger than Kirk, he'd have been born after Nero disrupted the timeline.

Answer (score 2):

Did not see it mentioned above, but there was a brief "comic" moment near the end of Star Trek V when Sulu and Chekov were tailing a Klingon woman before abruptly turning tail as she approached her bigger, burlier Klingon man.  Just a small suggestions that support Sulu was not gay in the original timeline at least.

Answer (score 0):

TOS tackled numerous social issues, but sexual orientation wasn't among them. The first foray for the franchise came at it sideways in the TNG episode "The Outcast" (Riker and the J'naii). The DS9 mirror universe stories took the issue a little more in stride with "mirror Kira".

Remember that as forward-thinking as the original Star Trek series was trying to be, it was still a product of its time (1960s), to be aired in family-friendly prime-time. Such topics were simply not discussed or even acknowledged.

A few tidbits could support the notion that the character Sulu is straight:

- In TOS:"The Way to Eden" he is seen enjoying a conversation with one of the female "space hippies"
- In the "Generations" movie, he is revealed to have a daughter (we are left to assume that he somehow found the time to start and raise a conventional family).
- In TOS:"The Naked Time", he appears interested in Uhura.
- In TOS:"Mirror, Mirror" he hits on Uhura (since demeanor differs considerably between the various characters and their alternate universe counterparts, can we really assume they are the same in all other respects?)