# Gay rights – does Star Trek ever address this issue?

Tags: star-trek

I am aware of the picture of the man wearing the 'dress' from TNG, which promotes gender equality, but are gay rights ever addressed in Star Trek at all? (All seasons accepted.)

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Takei said he spoke to Roddenberry about the possibility of broaching the gay rights issue, and Roddenberry seemed genuinely interested in the idea for TNG but passed on before he could implement it.

But the shows have touched upon the issue very subtly in some places, as [outlined here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexuality_in_Star_Trek#LGBT_in_Star_Trek).

For instance, Trill relationships have tangentially introduced non-heteronormative attraction as well as complex gender identities:

- Beverly's love interest, [Odan](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Odan), is later seen in a female host
- Dax obviously has been both male and female, and there are definite homoerotic undertones in her re-encounter with Lenara Kahn in *[Rejoined](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Rejoined_%28episode%29)*. To a lesser degree, her re-encounter with Enina in *[Dax](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Dax_%28episode%29)* also demonstrates a shared continued romantic bond with another woman.
  (Jadzia and Lenara's kiss was apparently censored in several Southern states.)

And there's also the introduction of races with non-binary genders/marriages:

- [J'naii](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/J%27naii), the asexual androgynous species from *The Outcast*, which [Soren](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Soren) belonged to.
- [Bynars](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Bynar), a genderless quasi-cybernetic race.
- [Vissians](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Vissian), a species with 3 sexes and genders where the 3rd sex was treated almost like communal property that's passed around to couples trying to reproduce.
- [Andorians](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Andorian), who—according to Data—require groups of four to marry. In canonical works, there have only been 2 genders depicted, but they could potentially have more than 2 genders, or 4 sexes and 2 genders (i.e. 4 different sets of plumbing, though only 2 culturally expressed genders).
- [Bolians](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Bolian#Society_and_culture), who have 2 genders but sometimes marry in groups of 3 or more, as implied in *[Field of Fire](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Bolian#Society_and_culture)* when Ezri mentions that Petty Officer [Zim Brott](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Zim_Brott) has a "co-husband" in addition to a wife.

And, ironically, the chauvinistic Ferengi race has also been used to explore trans characters:

- Quark gets gender-reassignment surgery in *[Profit and Lace](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Profit_and_Lace)*.
- [Pel](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Pel) is also forced to crossdress because of Ferengi repression of females.

There's also lots of homoerotic scenes in DS9 episodes dealing with the mirror universe:

- Intendant Kira Nerys' attraction to prime Kira appears to go beyond just narcissism. The show also hints at a sexual relationship with Ezri Tigan.
- Ezri Tigan later seems to hit it off with mirror Leeta.

Lastly, there was a sexy scene between [Raijin](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Rajiin_%28episode%29) and T'Pol.

For more info, see [this Ex Astris Scientia article](http://www.ex-astris-scientia.org/inconsistencies/homosexuality.htm), which lists some more subtle gay/trans symbolism in Star Trek (e.g. [Laas](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Chimera_%28episode%29) being an analogy for an openly gay character, [Pa'nar Syndrome](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Pa%27nar_Syndrome) and the perceived deviance of mindmelders as an analogy for the ostracism of the gay community and the perception during the 80s of AIDS as a "gay man's disease", etc.).

Comment: “Quark gets gender-reassignment surgery in Profit and Lace.” Ha! What a sensitive and nuanced exploration of trans issues *that* was.

Comment: TNG "The Outcast" confronted it pretty much head-on. The existence of Soren's "non-conforming" orientation and lack of acceptance within her home culture was a direct commentary on social attitudes toward sexual orientation contemporary to the series' production.

Comment: I think the Outcast doesn't get the recognition it deserves as a classic Trek story on the faults of present day civilization; yes, the morality is a little heavy handed, but it makes an important point on LGBT rights.

Comment: Is there a citation for that first line? I'm just surprised since recently Takei seems to have taken the opposite stance (http://io9.gizmodo.com/george-takei-tried-to-convince-the-team-behind-star-tre-1783306619).

Comment: @tardigrade I think you're confusing Takei's desire for Sulu to be straight with his not wanting gay rights to be addressed in Trek. It's well documented at this point that he's had at least one conversation with Gene about tackling gay rights in Trek: http://www.towleroad.com/2015/08/star-trek-gay/ http://www.blastr.com/2010/08/george_takei_roddenberry.php http://www.wgrz.com/news/nation-now/why-george-takei-didnt-support-a-gay-sulu-in-star-trek-beyond/266779408

Comment: The reason he didn't like Sulu becoming gay is primarily that Gene didn't write Sulu as gay. Trek isn't like comic books where there's infinite versions/retconning/ret-retconning to reinterpret and redefine characters. One can respect that but still want gay rights addressed in a different manner. Also, it's possible Takei doesn't like the notion that the character he played while being closeted just happens to turn out as gay. Perhaps there's a sense that he's being retroactively gay-typecasted.

Comment: Here is more detail on Takei broaching that to Roddenberry. http://www.blastr.com/2010/08/george_takei_roddenberry.php

Comment: From this it seems like the show is a lot more comfortable with homosexual relationships between females than between males.

Comment: @MishaR I think that's generally the case in a lot of societies. Straight men are often repulsed by gay relationships between men whilst lesbians are often fetishized (and extremely common in porn geared towards straight men). So depicting lesbians is less risky.

Comment: @Lèsemajesté At the risk of sounding cheeky, it really depends on your source of information. The adult entertainment industry is in line with your comment, but social statistics [described by the Pew Research Center](https://www.pewsocialtrends.org/2013/06/13/a-survey-of-lgbt-americans/) are more complex. While the view you describe exists among many Americans (as the PRC recognizes), the likelihood of a gay woman to be out is significantly less than that of a gay man; the age at which they come out also favors men. As a test of acceptance (rather than fetishism), this does not favor women.

Answer (score 14):

No.  At least not directly.

The issue of same-sex relationships was never brought forward in *Star Trek*.  This is in all the TV shows and in the movies.  The only time anything on screen came close to addressing this was in an episode of *Star Trek: The Next Generation*.  The episode [*The Outcast*](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/The_Outcast_%28episode%29) dealt with a race (the [J'naii](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/J%27naii)) that had only one sex, yet there were those who identified more with one gender than another.  Those who were like this and were caught were re-programmed to be "healthy" and prefer the "normal" monosexual relationships.

There was an attempt, within the 1st season, to address the topic.  [David Gerrold](http://www.gerrold.com/), best known for writing *The Trouble with Tribbles*, was a member of the writing staff at the time and wrote an episode titled *Blood and Fire* that featured two characters, *Enterprise* crewmen, who were in a same-sex relationship.  The episode apparently created behind the scenes tension and it was never produced.  Gerrold later re-wrote it for his [*Star Wolf*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wolf_%28David_Gerrold%29) series.  After that, he re-wrote it using characters from the original *Star Trek* and it was produced as a two part episode as part of [*Star Trek: Phase II*](http://www.startreknewvoyages.com/?page_id=389).

There are rumors that [Lt. Hawk](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Hawk_%28Lieutenant%29) in [*Star Trek: First Contact*](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Star_Trek%3a_First_Contact) was supposed to be the first openly gay character in *Star Trek*, but the producers of the movie have denied that.

Comment: [Er...](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Rejoined_(episode))

Comment: Just as an interesting aside, Johnathan Frakes heavily campaigned for a male actor to play Soren, Riker's love interest in the episode (The Outcast). I agree with Frakes, it would have been a cool statement.

Comment: Worth noting that Hawk **is** portrayed as having been gay in the *Titan* book series, since one of the main characters there was his husband. (As always, canonicity of non-TV-and-film sources is debatable.)

Comment: *Rejoined* may have two women kissing but that is not really the message of that episode. The central taboo in *Rejoined* is their expressing a relationship from a previous host -- the act is called 'reassociation' and it is grounds for exile in the Trill culture. The fact that no one in the 24th century gives a rip that the two are female is a deafening silent statement to be sure, but it was not the aim of the episode in the same way that *The Outcast* was a legitimate attempt at sex-same commentary. http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Rejoined_(episode)#Reception

Comment: @Stick Also, I don't believe the symbiotes _have_ a sex/gender

Comment: @Stick, my take on *Rejoined* was the bit about focussing on reassociation was a manoeuvre to be able to talk about gay rights without talking about gay rights

Comment: it's kind of a head fake - it seems like it might be about that, but really it isn't -- however, the idea that no one even brings up the same-sex relationship IS kind of 'talking about it without talking about it'. I recommend following the link I posted earlier, wherein nearly all involved with the episode staunchly insist that there really wasn't a hidden agenda; the episode was about what it was 'actually about', and the w4w thing wasn't 'a thing' because it isn't 'a thing' in the 24th century so there's no 'non-issue' to dance around.

Comment: @Stick but that's the point - they managed to make the episode about one thing while reflecting off the other.  But the producers and writers certainly knew how the TV audience would react to it.  That the in-universe story isn't about one thing doesn't mean that the episode is not.

Comment: I feel like we're all on the same team here :) It's true, they're addressing it via silence. It's compelling to see a story where a relationship 'just is' without turning the whole episode into a metaphor for gay rights. Compare to *The Outcast* where the central theme is very much *about* gender equality, just flipped and reversed. It's like the male pattern baldness thing - okay sure, Jean-Luc could undergo genetic therapy, but who cares? We have this huge galaxy to explore, who's fretting about hairlines?! Nobody cares! Oh, you're gay? *...and?!* Go be on a spaceship with the bald guy!

Comment: Actually, the silence has a lot of odd looks on set - it's fairly clear that the Bajorans, at least, are tolerant but not accepting of the same sex relationships; the starfleet crew seem equally ill at ease. Whether that's just the actors adding their own elements or not, or part of the direction given, can't be answered easily.

Comment: @Stick: I think *Rejoined* *was* addressing homosexuality through the metaphor or re-associating with a previous host.

Comment: "The Outcast" was all about homosexuality in a non-accepting society. It was just thinly disguised to make it more palatable to a conservative audience. Star Trek has given similar treatments to numerous social and political issues including the Vietnam War, racism, authoritarianism, class inequality,... they've also examined a few cultural topics like the hippie phenomenon of the 1960s ("The Way to Eden"). It's been a common "thing" for Star Trek to take a "current" topic and transpose it into a futuristic setting, going all the way back to its earliest episodes.

Answer (score 8):

Not really on tv/film, but as others have said, people involved with Trek have tried to incorporate LGBTI issues and have been denied.

In the expanded universe (novels, comics, games etc) though there have been LGBTI individuals, and off the top of my head I can remember:

- [Yoshi Mishima](http://www.comicvine.com/yoshi-mishima/4005-79209/) In the Starfleet Academy comic series.
- [Jayme Miranda](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Jayme_Miranda) and [Moll Enor](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Moll_Enor) from the novel [TNG:The Best and the Brightest](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/The_Best_and_the_Brightest)
- [Burgoyne 172](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Burgoyne_172) and [Selar](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Selar) in [Star Trek: New Frontier](http://memory-beta.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Trek:_New_Frontier)

In all of these instances I recall it being pretty much a non-issue for Federation citizens.

Wikipedia has a page that might be some use: [Sexuality in Star Trek](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sexuality_in_Star_Trek). Also [Homosexuality in Star Trek](http://www.ex-astris-scientia.org/inconsistencies/homosexuality.htm)

Also here's a link to [TV Legends Revealed](http://spinoff.comicbookresources.com/2013/09/11/tv-legends-revealed-star-trek-tng-wouldnt-air-episode-with-gay-crewmen/) where they talk about the previously mentioned David Gerrold's Blood and Fire episode, but there is a quote by Ron Moore, one of the writers on Star Trek, where they talk about the mindset of the time:

> "We’ve just failed at it. It’s not been something we’ve successfully
>   done. At Star Trek we used to have all these stock answers for why we
>   didn’t do it. The truth is it was not really a priority for any of us
>   on the staff so it wasn’t really something that was strong on
>   anybody’s radar. And then I think there’s a certain inertia that
>   you’re not used to writing those characters into these dramas and then
>   you just don’t. And somebody has to decide that it’s important before
>   you do it and I think we’re still at the place where that’s not yet a
>   common – yeah, we have to include this and this is an important thing
>   to include in the shows. Sci fi for whatever reason is just sort of
>   behind the curve on all this"

Answer (score 8):

The actor for [Garak](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Elim_Garak) has provided some insight into the issues with Star Trek and sexuality, and why he backed off from portraying his character as [omnisexual](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Omnisexual):

> Andrew Robinson provided non-canon insight into his role when interviewed by Amazon.com, stating "I started out playing Garak as someone who doesn't have a defined sexuality. He's not gay, he's not straight, it's a non-issue for him. Basically his sexuality is inclusive. But – it's Star Trek and there were a couple of things working against that. One is that Americans really are very nervous about sexual ambiguity. Also, this is a family show, they have to keep it on the 'straight and narrow', so then I backed off from it. Originally, in that very first episode, I loved the man's absolute fearlessness about presenting himself to an attractive human being. The fact that the attractive human being is a man (Bashir) doesn't make any difference to him, but that was a little too sophisticated I think. For the most part, the writers supported the character beautifully, but in that area they just made a choice they didn't want to go there, and if they don't want to go there I can't, because the writing doesn't support it."

I also vaguely recall once reading an interview with Alexander Siddig (the actor for [Julian Bashir](http://en.memory-alpha.org/wiki/Julian_Bashir)), where after being introduced to the character Garak he seriously thought that they were going to be the first gay couple on the series.  Unfortunately, I cannot seem to find it now.

Answer (score 5):

(I assume that "All seasons accepted" implies *any* of the official shows.)

It is more *indirectly* about gay rights (circumstantial evidence if you will), but *Star Trek: Discovery* features an openly gay male married couple among the lead characters Paul Stamets and Hugh Culber. There be on-screen smoochy times, and the history, evolution and struggles of their relationship are part of the series' story arcs.

A secondary character, Jet Reno, is a woman who has a dead wife, and discusses strategies for navigating and valuing queer relationships with Hugh in the episode "Through the Valley of the Shadows."

So gay rights are addressed in the sense that there is legal recognition of same sex marriages, and that same-sex relationships are apparently part of a normative set of permitted romantic relationships in Starfleet society (at least among humans).

Answer (score 3):

Roddenberry was once asked why a bald guy is commanding the Enterprise - surely by the 24th century we would have a cure for male pattern baldness? His famous answer: "By the 24th century, no one will care."

However, in the 1990s the prime-time networks were not quite ready for Brokeback Mountain in the Holodeck. In the 1960s it was *really* pushing the limits to put a black woman on the bridge. Note that the original first officer was female, but that didn't make it past the pilot.

So, extrapolating from 1966 (women as set dressing) to 1987 (bald men running the ship) to women captains in 1995 to girl-on-girl action shortly after, we can reasonably predict that, like baldness, by the 24th century no one will care about same-sex relationships and thus there's no need to air it today.

Comment: "by the 24th century no one will care about same-sex relationships and thus there's no need to air it today." By your logic, there would not be any reason to make a big issue about it, but that's not necessarily the same as saying as there's no need to air it today.

Comment: You have the start of a good premise here, but then your extrapolation goes wrong.  If your conclusion was just that the time had not yet come, but would have soon if the series had been continued (or something like that), I'd +1.

Comment: By the 24th century, no one will care that a captain is bald, therefore depicting a bald captain is perfectly normal --becomes--> by the 24th century, no one will care that a starfleet officer is gay, therefore we won't ever see a gay starfleet officer? There seems to be a gap in your logic.

Comment: No logic flaw at all. The extrapolation does jump a bit, but bald captains, blind engineers and female captains are supposed to be so normal that no one needs to talk about it. Gay officers are similarly non-issues, but do not have any outwardly distinguishing features (which would make them remarkable). It just wasn't Crusher's thing. The Yamato's captain could have been the next-gen Sulu for all we know.

Comment: Star Trek depicts a ton of romantic relationships. So the notion that gay individuals would never be identifiable is peculiar. It also doesn't make sense to argue that, because no one in the 24th century is homophobic, there's no need in to address that issue today. You may as well argue that Star Trek's commentary on racism, sexism, nationalism, capitalism, militarism, etc. were all unneeded because those are issues that the Federation has already outgrown. Star Trek's social commentary is for today's audience, not for a fictional 24th century audience.

Comment: A logical extrapolation from your example of Picard being bald would actually be to casually depict gay crew members being treated as normal human beings. One would expect exactly that in a tolerant and evolved 24th century society, because no one would care if you're gay/straight/bi, so gays in the 24th century wouldn't have to hide their homosexuality. Roddenberry wasn't saying "no 24th century audience would need to see a bald person commanding a starship, so there's no need for Picard to be bald."

Comment: "No one will care about same-sex relationships" strikes me as somewhat homophobic and queerphobic. **Presumably the people *in* same-sex relationships in the 24th Century would care about them, as would people watching *Star Trek* in the 20th and 21st centuries who care about same-sex relationship representation.**

Comment: @Lexible I don't think the answerer meant that sentence in the way you've interpreted it (though they might have done). It seems it might be best just to edit the answer to re-phrase that point. I'm not sure how best to do so, so please do if you can think of a more appropriate way of phrasing it.

Comment: @TheLethalCarrot Thank you for the eyes on, and thank you also for the gracious reminder to 'assume incompetence before assuming malice'. I struggle to understand paul's intentions with that last paragraph other than as I have aired above (and so feel unequipped to edit), but acknowledge they or someone else may indeed be able to rephrase it in a manner that reflects a non-phobic message. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

It was recently announced that int the upcoming Star Trek Beyond film, Sulu will have both a husband and a daughter.

Source: [John Cho Reveals Sulu Is Gay in 'Star Trek Beyond'](http://www.etonline.com/media/video/star_trek_star_john_cho_reveals_his_character_sulu_is_gay-192742/)
            
[John Cho Reveals Sulu Is Gay in 'Star Trek Beyond' (fans reaction)](http://www.msn.com/en-ca/movies/news/john-cho-reveals-sulu-is-gay-in-star-trek-beyond-heres-how-fans-are-reacting/ar-BBu4hSf?li=AAggSpD&OCID=ML11TD)

Comment: Interestingly, George Takei is [disappointed by this](http://www.hollywoodreporter.com/news/george-takei-reacts-gay-sulu-909154), feeling that Sulu was intended by Roddenberry to be straight (some evidence in [this answer](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/21280/22250) and the comments that go with it) and that it would have been better to introduce a new gay character.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if anyone said this already but there was an episode of Star Trek TNG when William Riker fell in love with a gender neutral being. Not sure if I recall the full plot or premise correctly but I got a gay vibe from the episode.

Comment: The Outcast was the episode. It was mentioned above. Out of universe, Frank's wanted the character to be played by a man, but the studio nixed it. So yea, slightly gay. Slightly trans.